Showing $H(B)_\omega \leq H(B)_\rho$ via concavity of von Neumann entropy
Denoting in the following $\phi$
with a pure state and $\tau$ as the maximally mixed state, furthermore $p\in[0,1]$.
In Wilde's quantum information theory book, according to eq. 20.111,
by the concavity of the entropy, that is
$ H(\sum_x p_X(x) \rho^x) \geq \sum_x p_X(x) H(\rho^x)$,
it holds that $H(B)_\omega = H((1-p) \phi+ p \tau ) \leq H(B)_\rho = H( \tau)$. How does this follow from the concavity of the entropy?

Why do you have a sum $\sum_x p(x)$? There is no dependence on $x$. How is $\omega$ or $\rho$ defined?

Thanks that is indeed redundant.

Consider the pure state $|\phi\rangle$. We can extend it to an orthonormal basis of the space $\{|\phi_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^d$ with $|\phi_1\rangle = |\phi\rangle$ and $d$ being the dimension of the space. Now define
$$
\omega_i = (1-p) |\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i| + p \tau\,.
$$
Note that we have
$
\sum_i \frac1d \omega_i = \tau
$
and so by concavity of the von Neumann entropy we have
$$
H(\tau) = H( \sum_i\tfrac1d \omega_i) \geq \sum_i\tfrac1dH(\omega_i) = \sum_i \tfrac1d H(\omega_1) = H(\omega_1)\,.
$$
Where for the second equality we used the fact that there exists a unitary $U_i$ (just a permutation of the basis) such that $\omega_1 = U_i \omega_i U_i^\dagger$ and the von Neumann entropy is invariant under unitary conjugation so $H(\omega_i) = H(\omega_j)$ for all $i,j$.

Is it correct that $|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i| = \mathbb{I}$? Then I do not see how $\tau$ is equal to $\sum_i \frac{1}{d} \omega_i = (1-p) \tau + \frac{p}{d} \tau $.

No that equality is not correct.
$$
\sum_i \omega_i = (1-p) \sum_i |\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|  + p \sum_i \tau = (1-p) I + p d \tau,.
$$
Dividing through by $d$ gives you the desired equality.
